# I want to output as many rows and columns as input in Java, but there seems to be an error

Tags: java

When I run the code, it just quits. No error code appears. Please understand that I have just started studying **Java** and am not good at using English.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Print the table");
        System.out.print("How many rows should we create? ");
        int row = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("How many column should we create? ");
        int column = input.nextInt();

        for (int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0; columnCount == column && rowCount == row; columnCount++) {
            if (columnCount < column){
                System.out.print("(" + rowCount + ","+ columnCount +")"+"\t");
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                rowCount++;
                columnCount = 0;
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

I see that there are already similar questions. However, my problem is that there is no response when I run the code, so I am sorry for asking because I cannot find the answer in the questions that already exist.
I'm trying to get the results below when I input the numbers one after the other. At first, I thought the conditional statement was the problem, but I didn't know what the problem was. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

ex)

```
Print the table
How many rows should we create? **5**
How many column should we create? **5**
(0, 1)  (0, 2)  (0, 3)  (0, 4)  (0, 5)
(1, 1)  (1, 2)  (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)
(2, 1)  (2, 2)  (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)
```

Comment: Welcome! Your English is fine. No worries about being a beginner. Your question is ok. If you want to improve your experience on this site, check the [tour] and [ask]. Your question could be improved with a more specific title. Make sure you include expected vs actual results of running your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop will immediately terminate as your conditional can never be statisfied:

```
for (int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0; columnCount == column && rowCount == row; columnCount++) {
```

This says: set `rowCount` to zero, and set `columnCount` to zero. Then repeat the following block as long as `columnCount` equals the value of `column` and `rowCount` equals the value of `row`. But you have already set `column` and `row` to some non-zero values, so that condition will always be false. I think what you mean is:

```
for (int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0; columnCount < column && rowCount < row; columnCount++)
```

So the loop repeats, incrementing the two counts, until the two counts match the input values.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response even though it was not a friendly question. Actually, I just used a double loop and had success with it, but after seeing your answer, I realized that the method I tried could also work. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, and your question was clearly expressed and well formatted. For reference you may like to look at [How to format posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop condition is wrong. You have comparing rowCount and columnCount(which are zero) to column and row(which are non-zero).
Please change to

```
for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) { // iterate over rows
        
        for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++) { // iterate over columns
            System.out.print("(" + rowCount + "," + columnCount + ")" + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is anything I have asked a question that has not been formatted in accordance with the culture or traditions of this community.